# How to project a shapely geometries to a different shape

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a template in the form of a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame with several shapely geometries that correspond to areas on a page.

For this process, the pages are photographed and I need the geometries in my template with the corresponding areas on the photographed page.  Right now, my "projection" of the template to the bounding box of the photographed page does not align with the photographed image.  I'm also pretty sure there is a better way to do this.

I've created a simplified example to illustrate:

I have this document, with both axes scaled to 1.

[image]

I created template that matches the objects on the image

```
shapes = [
    ('line1', LineString([(0.146, 0.216), (0.476 , 0.216)])),
    ('line2', LineString([(0.498, 0.871), (0.838, 0.871)]))
]

shapes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(shapes, columns=['name', 'geometry'], geometry='geometry')
```

Plotting that on top of the image we can verify that the shapes closely align with the shapes in the image.

```
plt.imshow(img, extent=[0,1,1,0], aspect=1.4142)
ax = plt.gca()
shapes.plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_aspect(1.4142)
```

[image]

I take a photograph of the same document get the bounding box of the page.

```
photo = load_image('example_photo.jpg')

bbox = Polygon([(0.847429096698761, 0.047594085335731506),
                (0.9442346692085266, 0.8787651062011719),
                (0.05563090369105339, 0.8789013028144836),
                (0.12740036845207214, 0.06380380690097809),
                (0.847429096698761, 0.047594085335731506)])

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.imshow(photo, extent=[0,1,1,0], aspect=1.4142)
plt.plot(*bbox.boundary.xy)
```

[image]

The problem is in the next step as I try to remap or project the original template into the shape of the bounding box.  This is what I have tried, but I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way to do this.  Also it doesn't work.

Summary of the method below is:

1. figure out which edge is top, bottom, right, left and orient them.
2. map each point into the new shape finding the intersection of the lines meeting each opposite side of the bounding box at proportionaly the same place as in the unit square.

```
def get_edges(bbox, visualize=True):
    '''Takes shapely polygon with exactly 5 points'''

    # check for 5 points
    if len(bbox.boundary.coords) != 5:
        raise('Polygon must have 5 points (4 sides)')
            
    #find top/bottom edge
    x, y = bbox.boundary.xy
    
    # remove last point which must be the same as the first
    x = np.array(x)[:-1]
    y = np.array(y)[:-1]
    
    # sort by y values.  Higher is closer to top, lower closer to bottom
    y_sorted = np.argsort(y)
    
    # get the index of the top and bottom lines
    top_points_idx = y_sorted[-2:]
    bot_points_idx = y_sorted[:2]
    
    # order the top point coords left to right
    top_point_order = top_points_idx[
        np.argsort(x[top_points_idx])
    ]
    
    bot_point_order = bot_points_idx[
        np.argsort(x[bot_points_idx])
    ]
        
    
    top_points = np.array(bbox.boundary.coords)[top_point_order]
    bot_points = np.array(bbox.boundary.coords)[bot_point_order]
    
    left_points = LineString([bot_points[0], top_points[0]])
    right_points = LineString([bot_points[1], top_points[1]])
    
    top_points = LineString(top_points)
    bot_points = LineString(bot_points)
    
    return top_points, bot_points, left_points, right_points

def project_unit_square_point(point, bbox, visualize=False):

    # check for 5 points
    if len(bbox.boundary.coords) != 5:
        raise('Polygon must have 5 points (4 sides)')

    # use the position as the portion of the each side
    x_scale, y_scale = point.coords[0]
    
    top, bot, left, right = get_edges(bbox)

    # find proportional intersections on edges
    top_point = top.interpolate(x_scale*top.length)
    bot_point = bot.interpolate(x_scale*bot.length)
    left_point = left.interpolate(y_scale*left.length)
    right_point = right.interpolate(y_scale*right.length)
    
    # connect edge points
    vline = LineString([top_point, bot_point])
    hline = LineString([left_point, right_point])
    
    # new point is intersection of vline and hline
    new_point = vline.intersection(hline)
    
    return new_point

def project_unit_square_geom(geom, bbox):
    
    new_points = []
    for point in geom.coords:
        new_points.append(project_unit_square_point(Point(point), bbox))
        
    new_geom = LineString(new_points)
    
    return new_geom

# project geoms onto form
projected_shapes = []
for shape in shapes.geometry:
    projected_shapes.append(
        project_unit_square_geom(shape, bbox)
    )

# create a new df for the mapped shapes
projected_shapes = gpd.GeoSeries(projected_shapes, name='geometry')

projected_shapes = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'name': shapes['name'],
                                     'geometry': projected_shapes},
                                    geometry='geometry')
```

Then when I visualize the result I get this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.imshow(photo, extent=[0,1,1,0])
plt.plot(*bbox.boundary.xy)
ax = plt.gca()
projected_shapes.plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_aspect(1.4142)
```

[image]

Close but not close enough.  Obvioulsy my approach is not working.  How can I map the template shapes onto the new shape defined by the bounding box?

Here are the original images to work with.
[image]
[image]

Comment: is that a printout? are you sure the page didn't have a margin? this seems like far more complex of an issue than a projection issue

Comment: Yes I am sure there is no additional border.  It was printed at 100% with no added border.  Even if there were the overlay would not be below both lines, it would be above the top line and below the bottom line.  Regardless, it would like to know how others handle the projection issue.